# Implementing Auto Focus in Camera App

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, autofocus

I am developing camera App ,i want to implement the Autofocus option in my app,i have searched in internet but i cant found any tutorial for that autofocus, can anybody tell how to implement the autofocus or please share the tutorial link .I am using AVCapture for camera

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial which will definately help you [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/)
`smoothAutoFocusEnabled` and `smoothAutoFocusSupported`
these property will be used for autofocus in camera application.

Comment: Thanks, Aayush Katiyur,let me try and let you know

Comment: Aayush Katiyur , i want tutorial with sample code for implementing the autofocus in camera app,

Comment: see this may be it will help you @user6183984 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848414/auto-focus-and-auto-exposure-in-avfoundation-on-custom-camera-layer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391203/focus-autofocus-not-working-in-camera-avfoundation-avcapturesession, https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/